# Mutually recursive coroutines with asyncio

Tags: python, recursion, python-asyncio

I had the hypothesis that if I wrote mutually recursive coroutines with asyncio, they would not hit the maximum recursion depth exception, since the event loop was calling them (and act like a trampoline). This, however, is not the case when I write them like this:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def a(n):
    print("A: {}".format(n))
    if n > 1000: return n
    else: yield from b(n+1)

@asyncio.coroutine
def b(n):
    print("B: {}".format(n))
    yield from a(n+1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(a(0))
```

When this runs, I get `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

Is there a way to keep the stack from growing in recursive coroutines with asyncio?

Comment: each time you 'yield from' you are hooking into the next call. Have you tried using a queue instead? That way you can hand off the information and dequeue into the next coroutine without linking them into each other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To keep the stack from growing, you have to allow each coroutine to actually exit after it schedules the next recursive call, which means you have to avoid using `yield from`. Instead, you use [`asyncio.async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.async) (or `asyncio.ensure_future` if using Python 3.4.4+) to schedule the next coroutine with the event loop, and use [`Future.add_done_callback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future.add_done_callback) to schedule a callback to run once the recursive call returns. Each coroutine then returns an `asyncio.Future` object, which has its result set inside the callback that's run when the recursive call it scheduled completes.

It's probably easiest to understand if you actually see the code:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def a(n):
    fut = asyncio.Future()  # We're going to return this right away to our caller
    def set_result(out):  # This gets called when the next recursive call completes
        fut.set_result(out.result()) # Pull the result from the inner call and return it up the stack.
    print("A: {}".format(n))
    if n > 1000: 
        return n
    else: 
        in_fut = asyncio.async(b(n+1))  # This returns an asyncio.Task
        in_fut.add_done_callback(set_result) # schedule set_result when the Task is done.
    return fut

@asyncio.coroutine
def b(n):
    fut = asyncio.Future()
    def set_result(out):
        fut.set_result(out.result())
    print("B: {}".format(n))
    in_fut = asyncio.async(a(n+1))
    in_fut.add_done_callback(set_result)
    return fut

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
print("Out is {}".format(loop.run_until_complete(a(0))))


Output:
A: 0
B: 1
A: 2
B: 3
A: 4
B: 5
...
A: 994
B: 995
A: 996
B: 997
A: 998
B: 999
A: 1000
B: 1001
A: 1002
Out is 1002
```

Now, your example code doesn't actually return `n` all the way back up the stack, so you could make something functionally equivalent that's a bit simpler:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def a(n):
    print("A: {}".format(n))
    if n > 1000: loop.stop(); return n
    else: asyncio.async(b(n+1))

@asyncio.coroutine
def b(n):
    print("B: {}".format(n))
    asyncio.async(a(n+1))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.async(a(0))
loop.run_forever()
```

But I suspect you really meant to return `n` all the way back up.

Comment: @dano, Out of curiosity. In your first code, if a and b are infinite mutual coroutines that never return, this will explode memory with Future objects. correct? What abount the second?

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.7, you can achieve the "trampoline" effect by using `asyncio.create_task()` instead of awaiting the coroutine directly.

```
import asyncio

async def a(n):
    print(f"A: {n}")
    if n > 1000: return n
    return await asyncio.create_task(b(n+1))

async def b(n):
    print(f"B: {n}")
    return await asyncio.create_task(a(n+1))

assert asyncio.run(a(0)) == 1002
```

However, this has the disadvantage that the event loop still needs to keep track of all the intermediate tasks, since each task is awaiting its successor.  We can use a `Future` object to avoid this problem.

```
import asyncio

async def _a(n, f):
    print(f"A: {n}")
    if n > 1000:
        f.set_result(n)
        return
    asyncio.create_task(_b(n+1, f))

async def _b(n, f):
    print(f"B: {n}}")
    asyncio.create_task(_a(n+1, f))

async def a(n):
    f = asyncio.get_running_loop().create_future()
    asyncio.create_task(_a(0, f))
    return await f

assert asyncio.run(a(0)) == 1002
```

Comment: Hi! I came across the problem to let the coroutine itself recursively start another one. But it seems to be really hard to implement: https://onecompiler.com/python/3xxn4busd  Could you tell me how to correct this code in order to generate 5 lines of print-outs?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to `async`, `await` and measured time. I really like how much more readable it is.

Future:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def a(n):
    fut = asyncio.Future()
    def set_result(out):
        fut.set_result(out.result())
    if n > 1000: 
        return n
    else: 
        in_fut = asyncio.async(b(n+1))
        in_fut.add_done_callback(set_result)
    return fut

@asyncio.coroutine
def b(n):
    fut = asyncio.Future()
    def set_result(out):
        fut.set_result(out.result())
    in_fut = asyncio.async(a(n+1))
    in_fut.add_done_callback(set_result)
    return fut

import timeit
print(min(timeit.repeat("""
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(a(0))
""", "from __main__ import a, b, asyncio", number=10)))
```

Result:

```
% time python stack_ori.py 
0.6602963969999109
python stack_ori.py  2,06s user 0,01s system 99% cpu 2,071 total
```

Async, await:

```
import asyncio

async def a(n):
    if n > 1000:
        return n
    else:
        ret = await asyncio.ensure_future(b(n + 1))
    return ret

async def b(n):
    ret = await asyncio.ensure_future(a(n + 1))
    return ret

import timeit
print(min(timeit.repeat("""
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(a(0))
""", "from __main__ import a, b, asyncio", number=10)))
```

Result:

```
% time  python stack.py
0.45157229300002655
python stack.py  1,42s user 0,02s system 99% cpu 1,451 total
```